# Step down converter stops regulating above 6V input

Tags: buck, converter

I'm currently using the following step down converter in a 4xAA battery powered design -> [TPS62745](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62745.pdf)

I have my Vselect pins configured as 3.3v out and using 4.7uH / 10uF combination on the output circuitry.

[image: schematic]

The coil I'm using has a Isat of 1.75A: [4.7uH](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/datasheet/74438323047.pdf) and my load is 80mA max

When I increase my Vin to 6 volt and more, I get these dips and increasing Vin results in the same dip line but lifted upwards.
So it doesn't regulate 3.3v anymore.
Vin on the scope screenshot was 6.6V and output 3.76V already.

[image: scope screenshot]

I replaced the cap to a 22uF and also tried 6.8uH coil but nothing changed.
The dips are every 100ms.

What is going on here?

Comment: Show a schematic and if possible a layout too, along with the load conditions.  Add a link to the datasheet for your inductor.  What's the rated Isat for the inductor?

Comment: Thanks @JohnD, I edited the post

Comment: Did you put any load on the output? Notice the output regulation is not specified for loads below 2 mA.

Comment: Also this part is internally compensated and only stable for certain L-C filter combinations.  Suitable output caps are shown in Table 6 in the datasheet.  If you're using something different you should make sure the ESR and DC voltage derating looks similar to the specified cap.  Even below 2mA I would expect this part to regulate well in PFM mode, albeit with increased ripple over PFM mode.

Comment: If your load is very light the PFM switching period could be 100ms.  Poor layout could cause the dips at the PFM rate.  What happens if you increase the load?

Comment: Oh boy, I rerouted a mosfet 3.3v to battery input 6v, but forgot one track to cut. So basically Vin was connected to Vout :S
Everything is fixed now.
Sorry for the confusing question.
Almost weekend :P